# SQL Group by combination?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am having problems selecting items from a table where a device_id can be either in the from_device_id column or the to_device_id column. I am trying to return all chats where the given device is ID is in the from_device_id or to_device_id columns, but only return the latest message.

`select chat.*, (select screen_name from usr where chat.from_device_id=usr.device_id limit 1) as from_screen_name, (select screen_name from usr where chat.to_device_id=usr.device_id limit 1) as to_screen_name from chat where to_device_id="ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83865900edbe" or from_device_id="ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83865900edbe" group by from_device_id, to_device_id;`

`+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+----------------+
| id | from_device_id                       | to_device_id                         | message | date                | from_screen_name | to_screen_name |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+----------------+
| 20 | ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83860033c587 | ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83865900edbe | ee      | 2011-02-28 12:36:38 | kevin            | handset        |
|  1 | ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83865900edbe | ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83860033c587 | yyy     | 2011-02-27 17:43:17 | handset          | kevin          |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------------------+------------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

As expected, two rows are returned. How can I modify this query to only return one row?

`mysql> describe chat;
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| from_device_id | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| to_device_id   | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| message        | varchar(2048) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date           | timestamp     | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select chat.*, 
       (select screen_name 
        from usr 
        where chat.from_device_id=usr.device_id
        limit 1
       ) as from_screen_name, 
       (select screen_name 
        from usr 
        where chat.to_device_id=usr.device_id
        limit 1
       ) as to_screen_name
from chat 
where to_device_id="ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83865900edbe" or 
      from_device_id="ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83865900edbe" 
group by from_device_id, to_device_id
order by date DESC
limit 1;
```

You need to tell SQL that it should sort the returned data by date to get the most recent chat. Then you just limit the returned rows to 1.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to use a Group By at all. Rather, you can simply use the Limit predicate to return the last row. In addition, you shouldn't need subqueries as you can use simply Joins. If `chat.from_device_id` and `chat.to_device_id` are both not-nullable, then you can replace the Left Joins with Inner Joins.

```
Select chat.id
    , chat.from_device_id
    , chat.to_device_id
    , chat.message
    , chat.date
    , FromUser.screen_name As from_screen_nam
    , ToUser.screen_name As to_screen_name 
From chat
    Left Join usr As FromUser
        On FromUser.device_id = chat.from_device_id
    Left Join usr As ToUser
        On ToUser.device_id = chat.to_device_id
Where chat.to_device_id="ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83865900edbe" 
    Or chat.from_device_id="ffffffff-af28-3427-a2bc-83865900edbe" 
Order By chat.date Desc
Limit 1
```